# round number in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello how do I round the following to two decimal places .

```
echo
     "<div class='quote-results-result'>ex VAT  £" .
         ((($_POST['qtylitres'] *  $price ['Price']) + $fuelmargin['margin']) / 1.2) .
       "</div>"
```

I need to round the price bit of a php novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round($VARIABLE_NAME,2);` //This rounds off the variable to 2 decimal places

Comment: `round(((($_POST['qtylitres'] *  $price ['Price']) + $fuelmargin['margin']) / 1.2),2)`

Answer (score 3):

Use number_format function like this:

```
$number = 1234.56789
$new_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
echo $new_number;

Output: 1234.57
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function from php manuals

```
echo round(3.4);         // 3
echo round(3.5);         // 4
echo round(3.6);         // 4
echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function roundoff($number,$format)
{  
    if($number != '') {
        $newNumber=$this->exp_to_dec($number);
        $num = explode('.',$newNumber);
        //pr($num);
        if(isset($num[1]) && $num[1] != 0) {    
            $dec = substr($num[1],0,$format);
        } else {
            $dec = '00';
        }
    } else {
        $num[0] = 0;
        $dec = '00';
    }
  return $num[0].'.'.$dec;
}

    function exp_to_dec($float_str)
```

// formats a floating point number string in decimal notation, supports signed floats, also supports non-standard formatting e.g. 0.2e+2 for 20
    {
        // make sure its a standard php float string (i.e. change 0.2e+2 to 20)
        // php will automatically format floats decimally if they are within a certain range
        $float_str = ( string ) (( float ) ($float_str));

```
    // if there is an E in the float string
    if (($pos = strpos ( strtolower ( $float_str ), 'e' )) !== false) {
        // get either side of the E, e.g. 1.6E+6 => exp E+6, num 1.6
        $exp = substr ( $float_str, $pos + 1 );
        $num = substr ( $float_str, 0, $pos );

        // strip off num sign, if there is one, and leave it off if its + (not required)
        if ((($num_sign = $num [0]) === '+') || ($num_sign === '-'))
            $num = substr ( $num, 1 );
        else
            $num_sign = '';
        if ($num_sign === '+')
            $num_sign = '';

    // strip off exponential sign ('+' or '-' as in 'E+6') if there is one, otherwise throw error, e.g. E+6 => '+'
        if ((($exp_sign = $exp [0]) === '+') || ($exp_sign === '-'))
            $exp = substr ( $exp, 1 );
        else
            trigger_error ( "Could not convert exponential notation to decimal notation: invalid float string '$float_str'", E_USER_ERROR );

    // get the number of decimal places to the right of the decimal point (or 0 if there is no dec point), e.g., 1.6 => 1
        $right_dec_places = (($dec_pos = strpos ( $num, '.' )) === false) ? 0 : strlen ( substr ( $num, $dec_pos + 1 ) );
        // get the number of decimal places to the left of the decimal point (or the length of the entire num if there is no dec point), e.g. 1.6 => 1
        $left_dec_places = ($dec_pos === false) ? strlen ( $num ) : strlen ( substr ( $num, 0, $dec_pos ) );

        // work out number of zeros from exp, exp sign and dec places, e.g. exp 6, exp sign +, dec places 1 => num zeros 5
        if ($exp_sign === '+')
            $num_zeros = $exp - $right_dec_places;
        else
            $num_zeros = $exp - $left_dec_places;

    // build a string with $num_zeros zeros, e.g. '0' 5 times => '00000'
        $zeros = str_pad ( '', $num_zeros, '0' );

        // strip decimal from num, e.g. 1.6 => 16
        if ($dec_pos !== false)
            $num = str_replace ( '.', '', $num );

    // if positive exponent, return like 1600000
        if ($exp_sign === '+')
            return $num_sign . $num . $zeros;

    // if negative exponent, return like 0.0000016
        else
            return $num_sign . '0.' . $zeros . $num;
    } // otherwise, assume already in decimal notation and return
    else
        return $float_str;
}
```